# Values depending of screen size

Tags: android

What if I need the `android:padding="120dip"` to be different depending on screen size and I don't want to create several other xmls?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/right_back"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="120dip" >
```

Comment: so you mean if there is small screen size then some other value, if there is large screen size then some other value and so ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you want different value for one string resources - based on the different screens, you can create different `values` folder the same way we have `drawable` folders:

[image]

In all folder, create **dimens.xml** and make sure you will give the same variable name in every file but different value.

### For example:

My **dimens.xml** in **values** folder is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="padding_val">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

So now, you just need to mention `android:padding="@dimen/padding_val"`.

But this is just for `values` folder, create the same dimens.xml file and put the value you want.

Comment: what shall I specify in android:padding="120dip"?

Comment: @siik see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension for a guide to using dimens.xml

Comment: @MrEngineer13 +1 for correct link. He might be not knowing about dimens.xml

Answer (score 0):

Dip (density independent pixels) is independent of screen size, which means, that if you define a margin 120dip, it will be proportionally an equal margin on each screen size.

DIP means: px * density factor, e.g. on ldpi the factor is 1.0, on mdpi 1.5 and on hdpi 2.0

So if you say you want a margin of 100dip it will be 100px on ldpi, 150px on mdpi and 200px on hdpi, which will be visually an equal size.